# Can't connect xdebug to PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have big problems to connect xdebug to PhpStorm 2016.1

Web server validation shows me that everything is ok.

phpinfo:

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.4.0
IDE Key PHPSTORM
Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   PHPSTORM    PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /home/dell/xdebug   /home/dell/xdebug
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

php.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/home/dell/xdebug
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

I have project files under `/home/dell/projects/dostawca/` and created symlink in `/var/www/`

Deployment server(in place)
[image: Deployment server(in place)]

Server under PHP->Servers
[image: Server under PHP->Servers]

I have configured "PHP Remote Debug" with key "PHPSTORM" and server "dostawca.local"

In current situation I still get "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'.
I also tried a lot different configurations/options of xdebug and PhpStorm, but nothing help(sometimes i get that connection is successful but nothing frames are shown, in other situation i got "Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'").

The new project directly inside `/var/www/project` and on `http://localhost/project` and without vhost doesn't work too

I haven't got idea what's wrong

Comment: 1) provide xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser; 2) Collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session and post it here. 3) What is your web server (Apache/nginx/etc) 4) How does you web server runs PHP (e.g.php-fpm/apache module etc)

Comment: 1) xdebug section is in my post 3) Apache 4) I installed it via apt so i think it's apache module, right? in processes i have only apache2  2) How i can collect that?

Comment: 1) that's looks like captured in terminal and not via browser... 2) `xdebug.remote_log` ?? 4) may need to come back after checking xdebug log.

Comment: 2) I set this but created folder is empty. I also try "nc localhost 9000" but it's empty too(or this command is wrong?)

Comment: It should be file and not a folder: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log Some Linux distros will have different php.ini used in CLI (terminal) and by Apache -- maybe you are editing wrong one? In any case: xdebug log is a must to see  here

Comment: File is empty too. Yes, i have two .ini files but i edited `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` which is loaded and I see changes in `phpinfo()`

Comment: So .. did you managed to solve it?

Comment: make certain your xdebug log file is writeable (by all to start, tighten security after).  You must see in there to determine what happens with the connection to the IDE.  Also, if you use php-fpm, change the port (php-fpm ships with 9000 as default port). When you have a port you can use for certain, restart IDE. Then enable 'listening' for incoming connexions.

Answer (score 0):

You have create an SSH tunnel on port `9000` for xdebug to work. Configure your authentication options accordingly (this tunnel uses a private key):

`ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 user@127.0.0.1 -i /path/to/private_key -p 22`

Also make sure to listen for incoming debug connections when running a debug session.